# 'if' cannot be used as a variable or function name

Tags: pine-script

I tried to make if in if in if, and i got error like this

Error at 358:19 'if' cannot be used as a variable or function name.

```
if TurnD1 == true
     if useallD1 == true
          if buycond and inTradeWindow
          strategy.entry('Entry Long', strategy.long)

          if sellcond and inTradeWindow
          strategy.entry('Entry Short', strategy.short)
     else
          if TurnLOD == true
               if buycond and inTradeWindow
               strategy.entry('Entry Long', strategy.long)
          else if TurnSOD == true
               if sellcond and inTradeWindow
               strategy.entry('Entry Short', strategy.short)
else
     na
```

I have tried a lot and it's not work even ' ?: '

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is wrong. Each block should be intdented by 4 spaces or 1 tab. You just have random number of spaces.

```
if TurnD1 == true
    if useallD1 == true
        if buycond and inTradeWindow
            strategy.entry('Entry Long', strategy.long)

        if sellcond and inTradeWindow
            strategy.entry('Entry Short', strategy.short)
    else
        if TurnLOD == true
            if buycond and inTradeWindow
                strategy.entry('Entry Long', strategy.long)
            else if TurnSOD == true
                if sellcond and inTradeWindow
                    strategy.entry('Entry Short', strategy.short)
else
    na
```